# Unable to fetch data using mongoose ,even when i have db and collection already in place

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

[image][image]

I have the data in my User collection inside the userDetails dB in mongoDB,the data scheme is as shown in the attached image.

Now on the node side I have written the following code to access the mongodb using mongoose,this code is split into three files as is as followed

MongoUtil.js

```
const urlMongo = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

client = async () => { 
    const newConn = await mongoose.createConnection(urlMongo,{ useUnifiedTopology:true,useNewUrlParser:true});
    return await newConn.useDb('userDetails');
}
module.exports = {client}
```

then I'm using the util file in Models as follows

user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoUtil = require('../mongoutil')
const { Schema } = mongoose;

  const userSchema = new Schema({
    email:  String, // String is shorthand for {type: String}
    userId: Number,
    password:String,
   
  });

const User = async () => {
    const conn = await mongoUtil.client();
    return conn.model('User',userSchema)
}

module.exports = User;
```

moongose.js

```
let User = require('./models/user');

getUserData = async() => {  
    const data = await User();
    const userData = await data.find()
    console.log(userData);
}

getUserData();
```

But i'm not able to get any data it always returns [],where would be I doing it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out the solution,and the above answer by sully describes the issue with pluralization that occurs in mongoose the way to solve it is when you create a schema can specify the collection name

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
   // collection: Student
    "Id" : Number,
    "Name" : String,
    "Subject" : String,
    "Marks" : Number

  }, {collection: 'Student'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
return conn.model('User',userSchema)
```

In the [Mongoose documentation on models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html), you'll see the following:

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name.

So if you want to use the model name 'User', you should name your collection 'users', not User

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the DB collection in plural form at the end of the schema. It solves the problem of `{}` if everything is correct in your Code. Look at this snippet for help:

```
const userModel = new Mongoose.model("userModel", userSchema);
module.exports = userModel;
```